# How can I add 1 to a column in R when A conditional is met?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am trying to fill a new column in a data frame (in R) based on the following conditional:

`df$B<- ifelse(difftime(df$A,lag(df$A))>minutes(30), increment(1),  increment(0))`

Here, the A column is time. So in A, every time the time difference between row i and row i-1 is greater than 30 minutes, I increment the new column B by one.

> A     B
> 1:00  1
> 1:31  2
> 1:40  2
> 2:30  3

Example

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example using dput() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you can use `cumsum` with `difftime` :

```
df$B <- cumsum(c(TRUE, difftime(df$A[-1], df$A[-nrow(df)], units = 'mins') > 30))
df

#                    A B
#1 2020-02-03 01:00:00 1
#2 2020-02-03 02:00:00 2
#3 2020-02-03 02:15:00 2
#4 2020-02-03 03:00:00 3
```

**data**

Make sure `class(df$A)` returns `"POSIXct"` :

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1580691600, 1580695200, 1580696100, 
1580698800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```